# Error:main method not found in the class, please define the main method

Tags: java, hibernate, session, transactions

I am getting the title error while compiling my java file. But I am not getting where is my mistake..Can anyone please help me? Below is my code:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;  
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
//imported UserDetailInfo class also here.. 
public class UserInfo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Session session=null;
        try{
            UserDetailInfo demopojo=new UserDetailInfo();
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            SessionFactory  sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            demopojo.setId(1);
            demopojo.setFirstName("Johny");
            demopojo.setLastName("John");
            session.save(demopojo);
            transaction.commit();

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to run it?

Comment: Using Eclipse..Its one of my java file from a project..Want to check this code only so using main method.Right click on the file name and Run as Java Application..And it shows me the mentioned error.

Comment: Has it managed to compile with no errors?

Comment: Did you SAVE the file after adding main? Clean the project and try Run again.

Comment: So in fact, it's when you run it, not when you compile it. Does the class compile? Look at the Problems view if you have any error.

Comment: I've cleaned the project.While debugging the file,now its giving me error :Could not find or load main class.

Comment: I have same error with eclipse. Did you solve it?

Comment: please let me know the solution if you find it.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem try to remove

> @SuppressWarnings("serial")

if you have it above main class. it worked for me.